# Slick2D: Initializing graphics object before game loop

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm using the Slick2D Java game library and I want to set the scale of the graphics object that gets passed to the render method in my game loop. I'd like to do this outside the render method, so that I would only have to call the setScale() method once. I am implementing my game as StateBasedGame, so I'd to like to initialize my graphics object in my StateBasedGame class. Where would be the appropriate place to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Init method, where you should be initializing your image. I can expand upon this, but your question seems to acknowledge that you already know how to scale the image.

**EDIT:** After rereading the question, the answer would be that you need to scale it every time you go into the render method of your gamestate object. This requires that you put graphics.scale(0.5f, 0.5f);

This is required, I believe, because the graphics object resets its scale every game tick so that you don't get a compounded effect as it calls the render method hundreds of times.

Comment: I attempted to call `container.getGraphics().scale(0.5f,0.5f);` in the `initStatesList(GameContainer container)` method but this has no effect.  My guess is because the Graphics object that is passed into each GameState is created anew each time?  Is this what you were talking about or do you have any further suggestions?

Comment: Oh I misread your original question. I thought you were asking to do something with an image, not the actual Graphics object haha (was a bit tired). As for what you're asking, it would be unwise to do this (read: properly handling singletons), but for what you're trying to accomplish should be in the edited answer above. If you want more help, post some code, and I will be glad to help you. I've done lots of work with slick, and know my way around it quite well.

Comment: Ok I see, thanks for clarifying.  However, doing it this way has a bit of a code smell for the way I'm intending on using it.  I'm using the `graphics.scale()` method in order to fit the game to any resolution.  If I have to call it every render, that means I have to put the same line of code in every render method in every state.  Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't really see much of a problem.. if you have 3 states, at most you'll only have to write 3 graphics.scale(gScaleX, gScaleY) lines..? And beyond this, there is also a class you could look into called ScalableGame, but I can't say that it's very useful. 

Also found a thread that contains some example of resolution fitting: http://slick.ninjacave.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=3107

Comment: Hopefully that thread helps you a bit further. I would try helping a bit more with my own code, but I'm away from the computer.